# Proper deletion of bad character strings in classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, owasp, zap

I performed a OWASP-ZAP security test on my classic asp application. It came back with a `Format String Vulnerability`.

The report says it used `ZAP%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n%s` as the attack for some form input field parameters (e.g. `username`).

The report suggests to

> Rewrite the background program using proper deletion of bad character
>   strings.

What does this actually mean in my case?
Is it in this case enough to replace special characters when using request() - e.g. replace `%` in `request(username)`?
Or do I have to delete the bad characters on the client side?

Reference: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Format_string_attack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a false-positive.  I would need to see more of your code and the input that was provided to it that triggered the warning from ZAP.

Taking any security-related action on the client side can never be trusted because client-side validation can be circumvented with minimal know-how.  You're left with performing sanitization on the server-side where the functions/subs doing the sanitization cannot be augmented.

Comment: Looking at [this article](https://blogs.iis.net/nazim/use-of-special-characters-like-in-an-iis-url) it sure sounds like a false positive since `%` is already a blocked character.